# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Ionic

Tags: php, android, angularjs, symfony, ionic-framework

Hello Friends I am developing android app using ionic framework.In the serve side I use Symfony framework for web services.I am successfully fetch data using web services.but when I post the data then I got error Cross-Origin Request Blocked.Here is My code:

```
.controller('login', function($scope,$state,Stack,$ionicPopup,$ionicLoading,$cordovaLocalNotification, $ionicPlatform) {




$scope.user = {};


      var username = $scope.user.username;
      var password = $scope.user.password;

       Stack.Login(username,password).then(function(response){

        var login = response.data;


        });  
  }

  $state.go('login');

})
```

Service is Like:

```
Login:function(username,password){
        //alert(info);
           var Url = baseurl+'login';

           var defer = $q.defer();
           alert(username);
          // console.log(item);
           $http.post(Url,username).
              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                  defer.resolve(data);
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  defer.reject();
              });

            return defer.promise;
   },
```

In Symfony:

```
public function loginAction()
         {
$response = new Response(json_encode(array('data' =>'Faliure')));
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lot of search I found solution of Cross-Origin Request Blocked. Actually the problem is in the server side.

The Solution is Install this:

```
php composer.phar require nelmio/cors-bundle:~1.0
```

Then add in AppKernal.php:

```
new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
```

Update the Config.yml file:

```
nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
       allow_credentials: true
       allow_origin: []
       allow_headers: []
       allow_methods: []
       expose_headers: []
       max_age: 0
       hosts: []
   paths:
    '^/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['origin', 'content-type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
```